# Button to move seekbar

Tags: java, android

I would like to have a seekbar with two buttons. One of the buttons would increase the progress by a set amount and the other would decrease it by a set amount.

How would I do this? Thanks

Comment: It's a year old, but you should have been told to consider doing your own research - Stackoverflow is not a place to have people do your coding for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need something like this:

```
Button increase = .......
Button decrease = .......

SeekBar seek = .......

increase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
      seek.setProgress(seek.getProgress() + toBeIncreasedBy);
  }    
});

decrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
      seek.setProgress(seek.getProgress() - toBeDecreasedBy);
  }    
});
```

Basically just set the SeekBar to have the current progress, and add or remove the progress you need increased or decreased.

Comment: Just want to point out that you should have - instead of + on the decrease button.